# Hide Visual or display better message on the measures or columns hidden by OLS

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

We have lots of datasets and reports which are currently being used by business. We recently started implementing object level security on our datasets to onboard new users. As certain columns are now hidden because of OLS, so new users are seeing below error:
"Can not display visual". This message is not very intuitive for end user.

Is there a way to provide better experience for these users. I tried to research for following options but it seems power bi does not support it.

1.) Hide visual on error - Not supported

2.) display a different message saying "You do not have permission" - Not supported

As of now the only option I see is to create separate reports on same dataset for different set of users. Please suggest anyone has achieved a better user experience by any manner.